# Does LifeRay provide a public official maven repository ?

Tags: maven, liferay-6

According to this [post](http://www.liferay.com/zh_CN/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Maven+SDK), LifeRay provides a maven plugin to support portlet plugin development,but not mention whether it has provided a public official maven repository.

Can anyone get to know about that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are these the artifacts you are looking for?  http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cliferay

Answer (score 5):

It's well hidden, but when you look at the sources for maven projects, that's quite easy. The address for the repo is https://repository.liferay.com/nexus/content/repositories/liferay-releases-ce/. You might want to skip https and go with http (I had some problems with the certificate for the server and maven refused to connect to https repo)

Comment: It requires to login.

Comment: That's a new development, it used to work without credentials… Anyway, https://repository.liferay.com/nexus/ is available for public